# How does this code store matrix in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to understand this program to read a 2x2 matrix and store it in the matrix. The elements in a row are separated by space and rows are separated by a new line.

```py
matrix = [[] for x in range(n)]
for i in range(0,n):
    matrix[i] = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

I do not understand how the list comprehension will jump to the second list in matrix with a new line

Comment: This is not a Stack Overflow question. If this code works, we cannot debug it. If you have questions on why something works the way it does, you can look at Python Documentation. If a moderator deems me wrong in saying this, I will remove this.

Comment: Because new line will be second call of ```input()``` (cause you terminate first step in your for loop only by committing```input()```, which will happen by you going to the new line) so it will replace second line of matrix.